# When does some specific encounter spawn and when doesn't?

Tags: path-of-exile

I'm farming Syndicate in Ossuary. I'm trying to find all possible hints that Syndicate won't spawn this time to restart the map asap. I know that they won't appear if there is mission for some other master (Eihnar, Niko or Alva) on the map already. But is there something else?

What are conditions when Syndicate encounters won't spawn?

I'm playing Synthesis Softcore league on PS4 if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description of [Betrayal integration into the core game](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/2330305), I expect you to have master encounters in 32% of Ossuary instances, so that Syndicate encounters will make up 8% of Ossuary instances. They should be random. In maps, you have Zana as another master, making up master encounters in 40% of maps, 8% being Syndicate encounters.

When a map instance contains Syndicate encounters, it will deterministically contain three encounters: one Intervention, one Research, and a pick of Transportation or Fortification. When a pre-map instance contains Syndicate, [it will contain a single encounter](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/2468422).

Depending on your hardware setup, you may or may not see higher instance loading times in instances with Syndicate encounters. This effect should be more pronounced in patch 3.6.3d, when [Betrayal assets are forcibly preloaded](https://pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/2486715/).

However, this effect is unreliable at best, and you will likely be more effective if you just search the instance with a fast movement skill.

Comment: both links are very helpful, I will try to test loading times. I also didn't know that Intervention and Research can happen together on the same map!

Comment: @arghtype just to make sure, you're aware that Syndicate encounters come in groups of three? One Intervention, one Research, and a pick between Transportation and Fortification.

Comment: you mean one after another? Or should it always have 3 Syndicate members on the same map?

Comment: @arghtype see updated answer

Comment: There are 4 types of Syndicate encounters, you'll get a random 3 if the Syndicate encounter is active. So if you encounter one, you know there will be another 2 somewhere.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud it's not exactly random three: Intervention and Research are guaranteed, see links in my answer.

Comment: is it true for maps too? I think I cleared maps with only 1 encounter in them.

Comment: @arghtype might be bugs here and there, but every location with Jun should generally have three encounters.

Comment: 3 encounters are now only possible in maps: "Areas prior to Maps will only generate with a single Betrayal encounter. Map areas will continue to generate with three encounters." from 3.6.2 patch notes - https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/2468422

Comment: @arghtype huh, I did not recall that. Thanks for pointing this out.